# Write data to TUN device but can't receive

Tags: python, scapy, tun

I have a TUN device, which named tun0.
Use below command to assign ip.

```sh
ifconfig tun0 192.168.2.1/24 mtu 1400 up
```

This is my demo written in python.

```py
from scapy.all import *

# Send to echo server, simulate UDP packet
pkt = IP(dst="x.x.x.x")/UDP(dport=7777)/"Hello tunnel"
pkt = IP(raw(pkt)) # calculate chksum
pkt.show()
# send(pkt) # It works
os.write(tun.fd, raw(pkt))
```

The server can't receive any request, but `nc -u x.x.x.x 7777` work. What's wrong with the program?